# How to add multiple links in the WordPress dashboard?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some php which adds a link in my WordPress dashboard. The problem is that m, whilst it works for one link, it doesn't work for two or more. So how do I add more than one link? Repeating the below php (which works for one link) simply breaks the site.

Php:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'linked_url' );
function linked_url() {
    add_menu_page('linked_url', 'Jobs', 'read', 'my_slug', '', 'dashicons-text', 1);
}

add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'linkedurl_function' );
function linkedurl_function() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[1][2] = "https://adsler.co.uk/jobs-dashboard/";
}
```

Also tried:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpso_custom_links_admin_menu');
function wpso_custom_links_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link One', 'read', 'https://www.example.com/' );
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link Two', 'read', 'https://asdf.com/' );
}
```

This didn't work at all and broke the site immediately.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into one of my wordpress sites and it worked fine. Something else must be going on.  Do you hook `admin_menu` anywhere else?

Comment: Which one? Did you copy and paste it twice?

Comment: If i copy and paste 1st one twice, it doesn't work. If i copy and paste second one, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I don't understand maybe what are you trying to do, but why using `$menu` global? For all you want to add use `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` functions

Comment: The second one is what works for me.

Comment: @GMarco So delete `global $menu;`?

Comment: @TheGentleman oh, didn't work for me at all. Perhaps delete `global`?

Comment: @9017 I think so. You might need to use `global $menu` variable if you want to get menu as it is and maybe change something. But if you just want to add new items in menu/submenu you don't have to use it

Comment: @GMarco24 no, it doesn't work with deleting it...tried it but it just said `page can't be found`

Comment: Write please exact structure of your desired menu and I'll try to write that for you

Comment: Ah, thanks very. So I need `Jobs` link, `dating` link `Events` link. Urls can be provided with example.com, just need to know the correct code.

Comment: Site is https://adsler.co.uk, if that helps?